# Как сделать Zoom, той области, которая выводиться на графике?

Tags: delphi, диаграммы, график

Мне надо сделать Zoom того, что выводиться на графике. Именно той области, где есть точки на графике.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точки выводятся по нажатию на кнопку `BitBtn6`

```
procedure TFDub2.BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if gr=3 then
 begin
     Form2.Chart1.Series[0].Clear;//Сброс
      Form2.Chart1.Series[1].Clear;//Сброс

    for i:=0 to Length(aXYiz) do
      begin
  //       Form2.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aXYiz[i][0],aXYiz[i][1]);
   //      continue;
         alpha :=Nl;
         beta := El;
         if (aXYiz[i][0] > 0) then
         begin;
          alpha := aXYiz[i][0]/parallel+Nl;
         end;
         if (aXYiz[i][1] > 0) then
         begin
           beta := aXYiz[i][1]/meridian+El;
         end;
         Form2.Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(alpha,beta);
       end;

  for i:=0 to Length(aXYizu) do
    begin
 //      Form2.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(aXYizu[i][0],aXYizu[i][1]);
 //        continue;
       alpha :=Nl;
       beta := El;
       if (aXYizu[i][0] > 0) then
       begin;
        alpha := aXYizu[i][0]/parallel+Nl;
       end;
       if (aXYizu[i][1] > 0) then
       begin
         beta := aXYizu[i][1]/meridian+El;
       end;
       Form2.Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(alpha,beta);
     end;

    Form2.Label1.Caption:=Edit7.Text;
    Form2.Label2.Caption:=ckm+' м/с;';
    Form2.Label3.Caption:=ck+' м/с';

    Form2.Show;
 end else
 FDub6.Show;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется вывод графика на всю область TChart, то можно сразу поставить в свойствах осей компонента TChart `Automatic` в **TRUE**.
Если это необходимо делать в процессе работы приложения, то так:

```
 CHart1.Axes.Automatic:=true;
```

Если же необходимо зумирование не на всю область, то необходимо, наоборот,  отключить автоматическое масштабирование по осям и делать что-то вроде (привожу пример, когда хочу получать график, занимающий только 66% от TChart по вертикали и 75% по горизонтали и сдвинутый к осям ):

```
d:=Chart1.Series[0].MaxYValue; // получаем максимальное значение ординаты
Chart1.LeftAxis.Maximum:=d*1.5; // меняем максимум для оси Y
d:=Chart1.Series[0].MaxXValue; // получаем максимальное значение абсциссы
Chart1.BottomAxis.Maximum:=d*1.33; // меняем максимум для оси X
Chart1.Repaint;
```

Также можно работать и с минимальными значениями осей. Можно использовать и функцию `Chart1.ZoomPercent(const PercentZoom: Double)`, позволяющую зуммировать график сразу по двум осям ( установив `Chart1.AnimatedZoom` в **TRUE**, вы получите плавное анимированное зумирование).